# What HTTP response codes are retried by python Requests

Tags: python, python-requests

What are the list of HTTP response status codes retried by default and how many times, by the Python Requests. How can I change the number of retries? I couldn't find any documentation for it.

I tried below code and there were two retries on `401` status code.

```
import requests
from http.client import HTTPConnection
from requests.auth import HTTPDigestAuth

HTTPConnection.debuglevel = 1
requests.adapters.DEFAULT_RETRIES = 5

def test():
    data = 'testdata'
    username = 'testuser'
    password = 'test'
    url='https://example.com:443/captionen_0001.vtt'
    try:
        response = requests.put(url, auth=HTTPDigestAuth(username,password), data=data, verify=False)
    except Exception as e:
        print('error'+str(e))

test()
```

```
  warnings.warn(
send: b'PUT /channel_captionen_0001.vtt HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: example.com\r\nUser-Agent: python-requests/2.24.0\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\nAccept: */*\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nContent-Length: 8\r\n\r\n'
send: b'testdata'
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 401 Authorization Required\r\n'
header: Date: Sat, 05 Feb 2022 07:50:25 GMT
header: WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="WebDAV", nonce="tE/JnkDX845db3", algorithm=MD5, qop="auth"
  
  warnings.warn(
send: b'PUT /channel_captionen_0001.vtt HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: example.com\r\nUser-Agent: python-requests/2.24.0\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\nAccept: */*\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nContent-Length: 8\r\nAuthorization: Digest username="testuser", realm="WebDAV", nonce="tE/JnkDX845db3", uri="/channel_captionen_0001.vtt", response="1c3299c716797e8f36528f6e6dbaeb50", algorithm="MD5", qop="auth", nc=00000001, cnonce="dd0835ef485c6b71"\r\n\r\n'
send: b'testdata'
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 401 Authorization Required\r\n'
header: Date: Sat, 05 Feb 2022 07:50:25 GMT
header: WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="WebDAV", nonce="/vXKnkDXBQc098a4", algorithm=MD5, qop="auth
```

Comment: I'm very surprised that *requests* appears to be retrying a 401. This is more likely to be some oddity in the logging. There would never be any point in retrying a 4xx code expect (possibly) 408. Some of the 5xx codes are worth retrying

Comment: This is not a retry. It is the typical flow of the digest authentication. At first the server answers with a 401 and additional challenge parameters in the headers, then the client sends a response to the challenge. You can see that the second request contains more data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not obviously to find. You have to know `requests` is not the package that manage the connection, `urllib3` does.

In the source code of [`HTTPAdapter`](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/_modules/requests/adapters/#HTTPAdapter) (use it when you want more control on `requests`), the docstring on `max_retries` parameter said:

> If you need granular control over the conditions under which we retry a request, import urllib3's `Retry` class and pass that instead

Now you can refer to the documentation of `urllib3` for [`Retry`](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/urllib3.util.html) class.

Read especially `status_forcelist` parameter and `RETRY_AFTER_STATUS_CODES` (default: `frozenset({413, 429, 503})`)

**Update**

```
import requests
import urllib3

my_code_list = [401, 403, ...]

s = requests.Session()
r = urllib3.util.Retry(status_forcelist=my_code_list)
a = requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter(max_retries=r)
s.mount('http://', a)
```

Comment: Maybe I missed something but the documentation for the Retry class doesn't indicate the circumstances under which it comes into play - i.e., which HTTP status codes might be retried.

Comment: @OlvinRoght. Can you check the `status_forcelist` please and `RETRY_AFTER_STATUS_CODES`

Comment: Worth noting that "By default, this is disabled with `None`"? `RETRY_AFTER_STATUS_CODES` looks like it refers to statuses where `Retry-After` will be respected.

Comment: Try to pass `Retry(status_forcelist=[401])` to `HTTPAdapter`

Comment: @Corralien status_forcelist is the answer. Why would retrying a 401 ever make sense? There doesn't seem to be a way to directly pass a reference to a Retry object to *requests* but there is a technique described here: https://findwork.dev/blog/advanced-usage-python-requests-timeouts-retries-hooks/

Comment: @OlvinRoght. `HTTPAdapter(max_retries=Retry(status_forcelist=[401])`

Comment: @Corralien I get that but why would one ever want to retry a 401?

Comment: Just for the demo purpose :)

Comment: @OlvinRoght *"why would one ever want to retry a 401"* - Retrying 401 is part of the challenge/response authentication scheme in Windows authentication. But that would require that the server sends the proper `WWW-Authenticate` header.

Comment: @Tomalak But retrying a 401 at the HTTP adapter level makes no sense. You would need the 401 to propagate back to the client who would then POST additional data to complete the authentication

Comment: @OlvinRoght Maybe there is a code path that transparently does this using the info passed to the `auth` parameter? Not sure why else they would do it. But I'm practically just guessing here.

Comment: I see server is responding with `header: WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="WebDAV", nonce="tE/JnkDX*845db3", algorithm=MD5, qop="auth"` for auth challenge. Thanks for the responses, the extra requests for challenge/response auth scheme is something that I was not able figure out. It is clear now.